# Why does a POST from Firefox to a Spring Boot app get 405 Method not allowed

Tags: java, http, firefox, post, spring-boot

I am trying to figure out this very strange issue.

I have a Spring Boot app using Thymeleaf for templates, and on my page, I have HTTP POSTs that work perfectly fine on Safari and Chrome browser, but just not on Firefox.

When I try to post from FireFox to my Spring Boot with a controller like this :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String post(@RequestBody LoginForm loginForm) {
          //process logging in, never makes it here when POSTing from Firefox
     }

   @GetMapping("/login")
   public String get(Model model) {
     //this generates the Thymeleaf template named login.html
     return "login";
  }
}
```

I have looked at some examples online such as switching PostMapping to RequestMapping, but it still doesn't work.

This is the frontend Thymeleaf template that tries to POST:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/login}" method="post" th:object="${loginform}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" th:field="*{username}"  autofocus="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" th:field="*{password}"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button><br/>
  </form>
```

So, on the actual generated HTML page, it looks like :

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" autofocus="true" name="username" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="12345">
 </form>
```

What else could I try? Thanks!

Comment: can u share how to calling this controller. share that code also to understand the issue.

Comment: Yes, I will update the original post with the Thymeleaf HTML template

Comment: can you show us the http packet or the form element in your html document  at runtime?

Comment: Sure @herokingsley , I will update the original post

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate you controller with @RestController instead of @Controller.

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String post(@RequestBody LoginForm loginForm) {
          //process logging in, never makes it here when POSTing from Firefox
     }
}
```

Usually for REST you would request an entity by a path variable, e.g.:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
     // do something with user identified by its id
}
```

To analyze your issue with Firefox I would suggest to open the developer view with <kbd>F-12</kbd> and compare the requests to a working request in Chrome.

Comment: Hi stacker, if I change this from @ Controller to @ RestController, my GET endpoint will fail.I am updating the original post with the GET part ( and I am using Thymeleaf). Also, the weird thing is why the POST-ing works fine on Chrome and Safari but just not on Firefox?

Answer (score -1):

For better you can change @Controller to @RestController, also add @RequestMapping in controller level, example added below,

```
@RestController
@Log4j2
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

@PostMapping("/login")    
public String post(@RequestBody LoginForm loginForm) {
          //process logging in, never makes it here when POSTing from Firefox
     }
}
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Hi Balasubramanian, if I change this from @ Controller to @ RestController, my GET endpoint will fail.I am updating the original post with the GET part ( and I am using Thymeleaf).   Also, the weird thing is why the POST-ing works fine on Chrome and Safari but just not on Firefox?

Comment: Umm your code is wrong. Or you literally meant /login/login mapping? Which is ugly?